# Clicking on Sumbit takes me to php page

Tags: php, html, forms, email, submit

I've taken the first part of this tutorial: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/custom-php-contact-forms/ and edited to suit my needs but when I click Submit on the form  it takes me to the php page.

When I click submit I want it to submit the form and the result of the form be emailed to me. I dont know PHP (hence why I was looking at a tutorial), so it is probably a really silly mistake :/

My HTML:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">

            <fieldset>

                <h3>Apply</h3>
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <p><strong>Recruitment Status:</strong> Open!</p>
                    </div>
                <hr>
                    <div>
                    <label>Minecraft Username</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Very important!" name="username">
                    <label>Which are you best at?</label>
                    <select name="BestAt">
                        <option>Mining</option>
                        <option>Hunting</option>
                        <option>Farming</option>
                        <option>PvP</option>
                        <option>Raiding</option>
                        <option>Building</option>
                        <option>Redstone</option>
                        <option>Other</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>How many hours are you online each day?</label>
                    <select name="TimeOnline">
                        <option>Less than 2 hrs</option>
                        <option>2-4 hrs</option>
                        <option>4-6 hrs</option>
                        <option>6-8 hrs</option>
                        <option>8-10 hrs</option>
                        <option>More than 10 hrs</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>What rank are you?</label>
                    <select name="rank">
                        <option>Default</option>
                        <option>Member</option>
                        <option>Tier 1</option>
                        <option>Tier 2</option>
                        <option>Tier 3</option>
                        <option>Tier 4</option>
                        <option>Tier 5</option>
                        <option>Moderator</option>
                        <option>Admin/Owner</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>What country do you live in?</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Which Country?" name="country">
                    <label>How old are you?</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Optional" name="age">
                    <label>Previous factions and why you left?</label>
                    <textarea rows="10" placeholder="One faction per line" name="PreviousFactions"></textarea>
                    <label>Why do you want to join Kando?</label>
                    <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Should be atleast 2 sentences" name="WhyYouWantToJoin"></textarea>
                    <hr>
                    <p>You may provide us with your forum username rather than email address or vice versa. It is required that you enter atleast one of them.</p>
                    <label>Email Address (So we can tell you if you've been accepted)</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Please fill in" name="email">
                    <label>Forum Username (So we can add you to our private forum)</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="one of these" name="ForumUsername">
                    <hr>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="AgreeToRules">Do you agree to follow our rules?</label>   
                    <hr>
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">Submit Application</button>
                    </div>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php $username = $_POST['username'];
$BestAt = $_POST['BestAt'];
$TimeOnline = $_POST['TimeOnline'];
$rank = $_POST['rank'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$PreviousFactions = $_POST['PreviousFactions'];
$WhyYouWantToJoin = $_POST['WhyYouWantToJoin'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ForumUsername = $_POST['ForumUsername'];
$formcontent=" From: $username \n Best At: $BestAt \n Time Online Daily: $TimeOnline \n Rank: $rank \n Country: $country \n Age: $age \n Previous Factions: $PreviousFactions \n Why $username wants to join: $WhyYouWantToJoin \n Email: $email \n Forum Username: $ForumUsername";
$recipient = "email@address.com";
$subject = "Kando Application!";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: When it takes you to the PHP page what does it display? A compiler error or "Error!" or "Thank You!"?

Comment: @George It displays the PHP code.

Comment: @JohnConde I don't want to see the PHP Code when I click Submit :) I want to see either Error! or Thank You!

Comment: @RoryTait Your form/code works. Why it won't work for you, could be a number of reasons. Is PHP enabled on your server, are you running this via WWW or local machine? Do your files have the `.php` extension etc. etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Would it be the fact that I haven't uploaded it to a host yet? If thats the case, I didn't realise you couldn't test things like forms when its not uploaded.

Comment: @RoryTait Ahhh there's the fault right there. PHP files do not run by themselves as would plain HTML files do. Yes, you have to upload them to your server and run them from there, unless you were to run your own webserver and install PHP on your machine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok right, ill upload to my host and try then - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to use google API key to send email through your page while someone submit a form. try to use this following php up oh your page:

```
    <?php
define('EMAIL_FOR_REPORTS', 'Your Email address here');
define('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY', 'Your website private key');
define('FINISH_URI', 'Your web page after submit a form');
define('FINISH_ACTION', 'redirect');
define('FINISH_MESSAGE', 'Your message to show for confirmation');
require_once('Your handler php file here');
?>
```

As you can see in above example, just you need to add handler.php to use it on your form page.

If you got problem, just give me a link of your test file that I'll guide you how to use it well.